# How do i fix my Berimbau?

Tags: equipment, capoeira

I have a berimbau verga that has cracked from the center while stringing it. 
Need a few tips how should i go about it; can I glue it up and thread it around the berimbau verga, would there be difference in the pitch later ?

Also, to make the verga look a little beautiful by putting some burn spots on it. Does that by any chance harm the verga?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  It is nice to see another capoeira practitioner here.  I removed your request for email you as well (you will get less spam that way) and the "signature".

Comment: Frankly, you're better off replacing the *verga*. Any patching you do to wood will create a weakness adjacent to the patch and will change the resonance and elasticity of the wood. I can't say how significant this will be, but the next time you restring it, it'll probably crack again anyway; you're just delaying the inevitable.

Answer (score 4):

You could try to put wood glue in the crack and than wrap the verga strongly with some cord.

But honestly i doubt that it will be possible to get the same flexibility. You will probably have to replace it.

Painting, slightly burning or even carving a good verga to add a personal touch should be no problem, if you go at it carefully.

Answer (score 3):

You can glue it back together and then cover the end with something hard. Usually it's a piece of leather, but leather doesn't hold up.
I used run-of-the-mill 2-part epoxy for a while and it would hold up decently before the wire would start to cut deep and it needed a new coat.
The best I've tried so far is JB Weld, which is a type of epoxy. It's very hard and durable, though eventually it will need a recoat.

I don't notice any impact on the sound from doing this.

Answer (score 2):

We have one berimbau in academia which got broken in the middle. People put some glue there and wrapped it with a thick cord pretty tightly (the kind which is used for atabaque). So far it's holding up but it has to be tuned carefully. So, in the long term, you can't avoid replacing the verga.